# Best Practice for PHP exit()

Tags: php, html

I am working on a PHP project and I have a file called login.php. This file contains a HTML code that basically consists of a form that has 2 inputs (used for email and password) and a submit button. Before the HTML there is a PHP script that checks if the inputs are valid (not empty, the user exists in the db). I use an hidden input field (called formsubmitted) to check if the user has pressed the submit button. If the values are valid then the PHP script redirects the user to the home page, if not, the PHP script prints a HTML div in which I store the error message and then the HTML for the form.

I would like to print only the error div, not the rest of the HTML, and for this I could use the exit() function. Now I don't know if this is a good practice, I have searched the web but didn't find any useful. I would appreciate if someone could tell me if it is ok to do so.
Thanks!

Here is how my code looks briefly:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    //check if the email and password are valid
    if (valid) {
        header("Location:home.php");
    } else {
        echo "<div id='error-section'>";
        echo "message";
        echo "</div>"
    }
}
exit();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...............
</html>
```

Comment: The exit() function prints a message and exits the current script.
This function is an alias of the die() function.

Comment: I would print the error message in the HTML.

Comment: As written, your code will never output any html except maybe that error message, since you're pulling the exit() OUTSIDE of your if() structure. you'll do the if() test, then always exit.

Comment: @krupalshah Going by [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), it's actually the other way around: `die` is an alias to `exit`. But your general point is correct.

Comment: Of course outputting only partial HTML is not “good practice”. Good practice would be to output that error message surrounded by at least a minimal, yet valid HTML document.

Comment: There can be some unexpected behavior with `exit()`, particularly if you're using FastCGI. For that reason, I would just print the error message in a more controlled way within the HTML.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a good question. He's asking if the practice is good. He's not advocating it.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question, for those people just picking up programing and PHP coming from the failed US school system (I was taught that `GOTO` statements were ok to use - within the last 5 years). Renaming the question title to: "exit() - best Practices" may be a more suitable title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question: I personally wouldn't use `exit()` statements anywhere in your code (unless it's after a REST API `echo(json_encode(array())` echo statement.) It just can cause a lot of head aches down the road with debugging errors.

(It also can break `\ob_*()\` calls as well as the majority of framework's display modules - because the framework won't be able to get to it's echo statements.)

---

### My Practice:

I always have a `.errors` div in my forms:

```
<?php if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors): ?>
     <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
               <strong>Error: </strong> <?php echo $error['message'] ?>
          </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<form>
     <!--- form here -->
</form>
```

[image: form errors]

This way you just pass the `$errors` array into your form and everything works honkey dory and you can avoid using `exit()` - using `exit()` has it's time and place, but because it doesn't give you a message or log anything it can be a royal pain to debug later on.

As a closing note, this method allows you to pass an array to the errors like so:

```
array(
     'first_name' => 'First Name Required',
     'last_name' => 'Last Name Required',
     'zip_code' => 'Must enter a valid zip code'
)
```

Which allows you to, when you're rendering your form add an `.error` class to your input fields which will help your users locate which input had the problem - always nice:

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" class="my_input_class<?php (isset($errors) && isset($errors['first_name'])) ? ' error' : '' ?>">
```

Comment: Nice solution. Professional.

Answer (score 1):

**try this :(UPDATED)**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
        //check if the email and password are valid
        if (valid) {
            header("Location:home.php");
        } else {
            die("<html>
                   <head>
                      <!-- ADD STUFF HERE IF YOU WANT-->
                   </head>
                   <body>
                      <div id='error-section'>message</div>
                   </body>
                 </html>");
           //you can use exit if you want too
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    ...............
    </html>
```

Comment: This will output incomplete HTML.

Comment: he said he didnt want to print the other html

Comment: Yes, but the solution should still be complete (`<HTML></HTML>`, etc.)

Comment: he can add it inside the die function

Comment: ...and, thus, no up-votes for this answer. The answer should be complete. The OP doesn't *know* to "add it inside the die function". Show a complete answer.

Comment: Just a word of caution, accessing the raw `$_POST` can expose you to quite a few vulnerabilities

Comment: Sir i do agree with you , :) i just helped with the exit/die issue but he should test the variable for "speciale" caracters ;)

Comment: You should not end your script with an `die`. It is poor design to rely on die() for error handling in a web site because it results in an ugly experience for site users: a broken page and - if they're lucky - an error message that is no help to them at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to show the form with an error message so the user has opportunity to try again. Not valid credentials can have several meaning. In any case you shouldn't just show error message and dead end for the user. Provide a meaningful error message with opportunity to try again.